# How to find list of 7 consecutive days of last month in python

Tags: python, datetime

I want to write a program in Python to find list of 7 consecutive days of last month in Python for example if today is 2019-5-9 then my output should be list of dates from 2019-4-8 to 2019-4-2 and for that I used datetime module of Python. I have written a program as below but I don't want output in datetime.date() format instead 2019-4-8. Can you please tell me how to do this. Also, give suggestions of other less time complexity and simple code.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

current_date=date.today()
current_year=date.today().year
current_day=date.today().day-1
month_before=date.today().month-1
date_before=current_date.replace(current_year,month_before,current_day)
month_list=[date_before]
print(month_list)
for i in range(1,7):
    month_list.append(date_before-timedelta(days=i))
print (month_list)
```

output is

```
[datetime.date(2019, 4, 8)]
[datetime.date(2019, 4, 8), datetime.date(2019, 4, 7), datetime.date(2019, 4, 6), datetime.date(2019, 4, 5), datetime.date(2019, 4, 4), datetime.date(2019, 4, 3), datetime.date(2019, 4, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format date using strftime

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

current_date=date.today()
current_year=date.today().year
current_day=date.today().day-1
month_before=date.today().month-1
date_before=current_date.replace(current_year,month_before,current_day)
month_list=[date_before]
print(month_list)
month_list=[(date_before-timedelta(days=i)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for i in range(7)]
print(month_list)
```

OR you can use pandas date_range and dateoffset.

```
import pandas as pd
date_list =  sorted(pd.date_range(pd.datetime.today() 
                                 - pd.DateOffset(months=1) 
                                 - pd.DateOffset(days=7) , 
                                  periods=7).tolist(), reverse=True)
print([dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for dt in date_list])
```

Result:

```
['2019-04-08', '2019-04-07', '2019-04-06', '2019-04-05', '2019-04-04', '2019-04-03', '2019-04-02']
```

Comment: thanks is there any way for my used method or datetime

Comment: Sure, pls post another SO question for this

Comment: Thanks I got solution